# â€” character showing instead of em dash (—)?

Tags: javascript, blob

The code:

```
var blob;

blob = new Blob(file, {
  encoding: "UTF-8",
  type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
});

saveAs(blob, "" + this._id + ".html");
```

It's strange if I imput an — in the textarea the download file shows a â€” (on Chrome) even though I specified the encoding and charset as UTF-8 (both textarea and html file viewed in the same browser). What could be the problem?

Comment: What is `file`? What "textarea" shows the downloaded blob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means you didn't decode the downloaded file; UTF-8 will **encode** the em-dash as three bytes. That means to read the downloaded file, you need to tell your editor (or whatever tool you use to read the file) that the file content is encoded as UTF-8.